# OpenVPN Connection Stops Randomly When Downloading or Uploading

Tags: openvpn

I have troubles with my OpenVPN connection. I tried searching for some answers but I could not find anything similar. Here is my problem:

My OpenVPN connection works fine while browsing and even passing a proxy through the VPN tunnel. BUT, the connection stops randomly when I download some file or upload something. The system does not shows any notification of the connection being dropped and seem it is still connected, my computer losses Internet connection. I am running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.

```
$ openvpn --version
  OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  2 2016
```

Note:
If I tether from my phone through USB and the phone connected to OpenVPN (not the computer), all traffic goes normally and I can upload/download normally.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenVPN with trust.zone as per their settings, would drop the VPN connection without warning or error message and just use the wired connection, thus losing security of the VPN. Seemingly random events but it had happened when I went back to it after screensaver had kicked in. Disabling the screensaver (Ubuntu 17.04) fixed things and I haven't had a dropout since. No, I don't know why this is so either. Just a quirk of Linux, I suppose.